# What's the difference between importing and extending a class?

Tags: java

What's the difference between importing and extending a class in Java

Comment: ... or did you mean "implements" vs "extends"?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Those are two very different things.

Importing a class, is making it so you can use that class without needing to qualify the full name in the current class you are writing.

```
import java.util.Scanner
// now you can use the Scanner class in your code like so:
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
// instead of having to do
java.util.Scanner stdin = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```

Extending a class is creating a new class that is a subclass of some other class.  This will allow you to add or change functionality of the class you are extending.

```
// this is a very contrived example
public class EmptyList extends ArrayList {
    @Override
    public boolean add(Object o){
        return false; // will not add things to a list
    }
}
```

Comment: Will not compile, add has to return true or false!

Comment: @Tim, why won't it compile?  Just because of the missing return value?

Comment: @Justin - you may want to clarify that importing means "you can use that class in the current class **without qualification** ".  You can still *use* `Scanner` without importing it, you'll just need to refer to it as `java.util.Scanner` throughout the source.  To me this is an important point; importing a class doesn't "do" anything, it's merely syntactic sugar to make subsequent declarations shorter.

Comment: very well explained. Simplest and easiest explanation

Answer (score 6):

Import doesn't change your program, it just allows you to write the short form of declaring a class. In your own class you can use any other class from any package within the Java library.
Lets say you want to use the Scanner class to take input from the keyboard. Instead of writing `java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);`, you can simply write `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`.
If you import the package or a package followed by the class name at the top of your class which is import `java.util.*;` or i`mport java.util.Scanner;`

Extending a class is not as simple as importing a class. When you extend a class you are adding all instances (fields) and methods of the extended class into your own class. In other words, you have access to all of the fields and methods of the extended class.

Comment: Not private ones. (Why answer am old question like this that already has a good, accepted answer?)

Answer (score 4):

When, in your class, you reference a class that is not in the same package as your class, you need to *import* the other one.

When you want to use oop [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29), you *extend* a class - i.e. your class has the functionality of the superclass + whatever your write in your class.

The two things are rather different, so perhaps you should create some simple programs, and see for yourself the obvious difference.

Answer (score 4):

Importing means that you can reference it in a non-qualified way. e.g.

```
import java.util.List;

List list = ...
```

as opposed to

```
java.util.List list =
```

Extending is *completely different*, and means inheriting behaviour and structure from a class

Answer (score 3):

In Simple:

Import refers to **Has a** relationship. With keyword ***new***.

Extend refers to **IS a** relationship. With keyword ***extends***.

Please refer [this](http://learnwithharsha.com/my-first-java-lesson-is-a-and-has-a-relationships/) link for good example.

Answer (score 1):

**Extending**
Extending means enhancing the functionality of an existing class.
**Importing**
Importing means use some api as a helper to your class for desinging.

Answer (score 1):

first of all ,import is use to increase the efficiency of compiler to find the correct class
the main difference ,is the import use aggregation(has-a) concept & in extends we use (is-a) relation
in has-a or import , the obj of our class is not maintain a lifetime relation with import classes we need to get the obj of particular class that we want to use in our application 
but in extends the obj of our class is make a life time relation with parent class...
HAPPY if i am right other wise give right ans....

Answer (score 1):

importing a class provides us to access its predefined methods.we cnn't chnge those methods but we can use them. extending a class means we can override the methods defined in the class to be inherited.

Answer (score 0):

Package import is just a way to tell the classloader where to look for your classes and also differentiate between classes with the same name. Class extend tells JVM the heirarchical relationship between your classes. OO rules apply once the class is found.

Answer (score -4):

Import is a optional clause that declare which class you will use in you potential class interface or enumeration. The extend says to class that she can use the functionality of that parent class.

To extend a public class you need to import it first.

Comment: This is almost entirely wrong.  You can extend a class without importing it.  You can use a class without importing it, so imports don't form a "declaration of intention".  And extension has many ramifications beyond access rights, only lets a class access `protected` members of the parent, and is not necessary to use `public` functionality of the parent in any case.

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle: We can say that it is possible to extend class not using import key word but add the whole path to it. You are true about that "declaration of intention". in other word if i wrote smtg like this "To extend a class public class you should import it or use full path", that was a tremendous my mind short cut. I happens ;-).