# How to correctly write the extends functionality instead of import statement?

Tags: java

Instead of import statement , I am using extends attribute for java.util.Scanner class.I am getting error with below code snippet.How to correct it?

```
 class test extends java.util.Scanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the value from keyboard:");
      int ans = sc.nextInt();
      System.out.println("The value entered through keyboard ::"+ans);
    }
 }
```

Comment: That is not how you do things and even so you still need to do `import`

Comment: I think your are looking for [What's the difference between importing and extending a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468252/whats-the-difference-between-importing-and-extending-a-class)

Comment: No, you don't need imports.  You can fully qualify each reference.  But even so Scanner is final.  You could wrap it (see below), and implement the appropriate interfaces, but you can't substitute your class for a scanner in calls that already take a scanner.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: you can't because java.util.Scanner is final and you cannot extend it.

But, you can using encapsulation as follow, in same package create a new class MyScanner:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyScanner implements Iterator<String>, Closeable {

    private Scanner scanner;

    public MyScanner(InputStream in) {
        this.scanner = new Scanner(in);
    }

    //Override classes you need

}
```

and use it in your class:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyScanner {

    private Scanner scanner;

    public MyScanner(InputStream in) {
        this.scanner = new Scanner(in);
    }

    public int nextInt() {
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }

}
```

Be aware that solution here is to declare two classes in same package

Comment: You should implement Iterator<String>, Closeable

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend the `Scanner` class since it's final.

Even if it was possible, extending `Scanner` doesn't allow you to eliminate the `import` statement when you refer to the `Scanner` class without the package name.

It makes no sense to extend `Scanner` for the given code. If you want to avoid the `import` statement, use the full class name:

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the value from keyboard:");
        int ans = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The value entered through keyboard ::"+ans);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` is a `final` class and can therefore not be extended.

If you want to use the scanner without importing it explicitely, you could try the following:

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in); // Specify full class path over here
        System.out.println("Enter the value from keyboard:");
        int ans = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The value entered through keyboard ::"+ans);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind the naming conventions: a class name should start with an uppercase letter.